# Почему OpenServer стучится на s-server.ru?

Tags: openserver

Установил [OpenServer](http://open-server.ru/). Он постоянно стучится на [s-server.ru](http://s-server.ru). В чём причина и как это исправить?

Comment: Немного отредактировал. Добавьте ещё ссылку на сайт этого сервера, чтобы каждому читающему не приходилось гуглить, чтобы понять вопрос.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Openserver проверяет наличие обновлений с `open-server.ru`. Неймсервера у этого сайта - `ns1.s-server.ru` и `ns2.s-server.ru`. Поэтому именно туда он и стучится с DNS запросом "какой ip у сайта `www.open-server.ru`?"

Comment: Подскажите, какой виндовый софт удобно использовать, чтобы смотреть что именно пытается отправить программа?

Comment: лдя http(s) - Fiddler. для остального - Wireshark